# Check if folder content is equal in two folders - c++ & Linux

Tags: c++, linux, hash, md5

I am looking for a simple fast way of checking is 2 folders has the same content

The folders are on two different computers so i need a function with:

```
input: path to folder
output: number (like checksum) to compare
```

I know how to run it in Linux with 
`md5sum` or `sha1sum`,
but is there a way doing it in C++ and for all the items in the folder?

Comment: Using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system could be a good start.

Comment: @K.Kirsz Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) over that one.

Comment: **Not Clear Enough** also **Much General**. You have so may ways to do this. First of all you can use `boost` **file system**. other that, you can use **system** that is not very good idea. other than you can use **fork and exec** family file system